# Large Structured Programming with Compile

Tags: function-construction, programming, compile, function-compile

Is it possible or wise to build a large program structure with only `Compile`?

With `FunctionCompile` it is possible to create compiled code while setting an environment, where stand-alone subroutines can be defined. (see [CompilerEnvironment](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompilerEnvironment.html))

I was wondering however if it was possible to have subroutines included in compilation, which access variables not initially defined inside them (similar to "INCLUDE" from Fortran or the way pure functions can access global variables in a kernel session)?

I have managed something similar to this using `Compile` and `Block` while setting `InlineCompiledFunctions -> True` as demonstrated below.
However this leaves me with the problem that the subroutines to not work outside the compiled evaluation and code testing and debugging is difficult and strings are not supported in `Compile`.

```
ExecuteSubroutine = Compile[{},
    Block[{transIndex,transVec,coordVecNew},
        (* specify the change *)
        transIndex = RandomInteger[{1,Length@coordVecC}];
        transVec = RandomReal[{-1,1},3];
        
        (* calculate new coordinates *)
        coordVecNew = coordVecC[[transIndex]] + ConstantArray[transVec,Length@coordVecC[[transIndex]]];
        
        (* update the global variable *)
        coordVecC[[transIndex]] = coordVecNew;
    ];
    ,{{coordVecC,_Real,3}}
];
```

```
ExecuteSimulation = Compile[{{coordVecInit,_Real,3}},
    Block[{coordVecC},
        
        (*initalize local variables*)
        coordVecC = coordVecInit;
    
        (*Execute Subroutine*)
        Do[
            ExecuteSubroutine[];
            ,{10}
        ];

        (*Output the edited system state*)
        coordVec = coordVecC;
    ]
    ,CompilationTarget->"WVM"
    ,RuntimeOptions->"Speed"
    ,CompilationOptions->{
        "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True,
        "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True
    }
];
```

```
(*To execute the function*)
coordVec = RandomReal[{0,10},{500,1,3}];;
ExecuteSimulation[coordVec]
```

Is this way of building a compiled fast evaluating code good or are there better ways to include such subroutines?

Comment: Possible? Yes. Wise? No. It is not meant for that. For really complex problems that have to be compiled I would rather suggest to code in C++ and then to link to _Mathematica_ via LibraryLink or LTemplate.

Comment: I for one would be interested in how far one could push this. Many times I feel that MMA only works for toy problems and when one tries to do something that is big then it fails. Push the compile envelope and tell us how it goes.